# dynamic aggregated clustering? points on plane

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, computational-geometry

Problem:

I have millions (10+) of markers, each with various fields:

```
 1. lat 
 2. lng   
 3. area (double)
 4. size (int)
 5. tolerance (double)
 6. lags (boolean)
 7. channel (boolean)
... (more)
```

Now, I want each cluster to have the following aggregated data:

```
 1. number of markers
 2. min area
 3. max area
 4. avg area
 5. min size
 6. max size
 7. avg size
 8. tolerance distribution (how many where of tolerance < X, other >=X < Y and >=Y <Z where X,Y,Z constants)
 ... (more)
```

clusters are created based on lat,lng of the markers (distance wise) and based on zoom level (int).

Non problematic part(**):

> Calculating the clusters for all zoom-level, regardless of the
> condition "all-in". This is done by creating a tree and the fetching of clusters for the user is straight-forward.

Now for problem:

> Users can query based on the marker fields, e.g "show me all markers
> that their area > K and lags = true". For this query alone, a whole
> new clusters tree needs to be created. If he changes the query "show
> me all markers that their area > K.0001 and lags=true" and new tree
> will have to be created.  I don't want to calculate such tree for
> every user's query and not to store it in-memory (not sure if it's
> possible).

Question:

```
What approach should be taken?
given the complexity of calculation X # of markers 
(fields inside) X speed factor. 
I was thinking that there's some sort of way to use  the 
"all-in" clusters calculation(**), as it gives me ALL the markers and clusters and from 
there to manipulate in some elegant way.
```

Will:

```
 - space-filling-curve (hilbert) can help? how?  
 - DB approach (what DBand why?)
 - k-d tree ?
```

The whole idea is to handle large amount of data and calculation pre-hand so the user can manipulate it with-out calculating it on his side or the server-side (so client side clustering is not a solution, fusion tables as well)

Code samples are more than welcome.

Comment: I think it will be difficult to manage all the stuff you want in Hadoop MapReduce. Thus for your database approach, this reading: http://www.directionsmag.com/articles/nosql-databases-what-geospatial-users-need-to-know/164635

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is good for *pre-processing*, not for online ("live") operation.

Hilbert curves and k-d-trees are more complex and actually less useful for you than a regular grid-file / quadtree. Optimize the tree to exactly match your visualization zoom levels! Then you may get away without doing any "clustering" at all, but just visualize the appropriate quadtree cells.

After all, your spatial data is only 2d, so all the 2d methods will work just fine. And you know the value range very well, as the earth doesn't change size. This is why Google Maps is this fast: they use fixed tiles they can cache, serve efficiently and pregenerate.

Given that you probably don't need ACID and transactions and these advanced features, using one of the hyped NoSQL-Databases seems reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this doesn't solve my question. Reason is, i need to understand the mix / or the explicity algorithm for an optimized solution. You wrote "match your visualization zoom levels", what do you mean? Notice that my queries are dynamic (multiple range + boolean) and the clusters are calculated everytime per user (bad). i'm trying to find a way to use the surface-filling-curve (hilbert) for "all results" and derive from it per user query.. or something similar.

Comment: Google Maps queries are also dynamic, yet the display uses *precomputed tiles*. You can always clip them easily. Precompute the results for an appropriate grid, then refine them for the exact query. Much faster than messing around with hilbert curves (which doesn't really save you the refining either).

Comment: That's not feasible, reason is: let's say i have 6 different range fields (several with unsigned int, several floats) and 30 booleans from all the EACH user can choose. Your solution is to pre-compute all possible combinations. So, if a user searchs for the all results with area >= 100.321 and area <= 238.4 and also channel is set to true. That's 1 combination for 1 tree, for all combinations i'd have such a big number that it won't be feasible. SFC can help only with mapping.

Comment: You maybe don't need to precompute all combinations, but only the actual spatial attributes.
I've used SFCs, and I don't think they will help you here. Obviously, they will in particular not work for booleans either!

Comment: Sure, but only based on the spatial attributes (lat,lng) will help me build the clusters that have ALL the data points , but that won't help me with a dynamic query , to reduce from ALL to specific. If you ment something else, i really didnt understand it, so please explain in details or with some source.

Comment: In high-dimensional data, it often pays off to index only the most selective attributes. Indexing everything - in particular when you have abnormal attributes that don't have a spatial spread - may fail badly. So yes, it may be a good strategy to use a grid based approach for the spatial attributes only, and just filter out the others linearly then.